# MapAction.setCenterAndZoom(...) throws NoClassDefFoundException on 9780

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-maps

this is a little weird to me,
When I center the map with `MapAction.setCenterAndZoom(...)` or `MapDimensions.setCenter(...)` on both BB 9780 Device and Simulator, it throws a NoClassDefFoundException
but when I try the same code on 9930 simulator it works fine.
I've even tried another code (`MapActionDemo`) on 9780, it thrown the same exception. 
I also checked the application permissions and they were all fine.
so, can you please tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundException` is often a sign that you use some newer API on a device that supports an older version => first thing I'd do in that case would be to check for version compatibility

Comment: Just to be clear, I think API v6.0 works fine on 9780, and I'm using API v6.0, could the app been built successfully if those functions are not compatible with v6.0? am I missing something? I'm sorry I'm not that good at java configurations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per API documentation, `MapAction.setCenter...` appears available only since version 7.0. This is most likely reason why BB 9780 device and simulator fail to run it while 9930 executes successfully.

As far as I can tell there is a chance to make your code work if you hack method names to `setCentre...` instead of `setCenter...`

## references

- [MapAction API docs for BB 6](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/maps/ui/MapAction.html) - setCentre is there, setCenter is not there
   
  [MapAction API docs for BB 7](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/maps/ui/MapAction.html) - setCentre is declared deprecated, setCenter is there
- [BB 9780 specification](http://www.gsmarena.com/blackberry_bold_9780-3431.php) declares support for BB OS 6
   
  [BB 9930 specification](http://www.gsmarena.com/blackberry_bold_touch_9930-3755.php) declares support for BB OS 7